# Using RegEx to remove start and end pattern

Tags: regex

I need to parse this string.

```
     \n        \nnabcn     \n      \n
```

I need to extract `"nabcn"` from that. White spaces and `"\n"` are random and can be in any order. Note: `"\n"` is text not escape character.

`"nabcn"` can have any characters including newline. My requirement is just to not have combinations of the white spaces and `"\n"` string before and after desired text.

This is what I came up with:

```
(?=[^\s(?:\\n)])((?:(?:.|\n)*)?)(?<=[^\s(?:\\n)])
```

This works but the problem is it finds only "abc".

Comment: Why not just remove all whitespaces and `\n` from input?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's what I came up with](http://regexr.com/3ggdj):

```
(?:\\n)(\w+)
```

This should capture `nabcn` in Group 1. You can see this in the Regexr link above under "Details".

The first parenentheses specify a non-capture group looking for `\n`, the second looks for words `\w` greedily.

Comment: Works only for this particular desired text. Try adding  some spaces and "\n" between nabcn. For example - 

   \n   \n        \nna      \n      bcn     \n      \n    

That gave me 'na' only. It should have extracted 'na      \n      bcn'

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
(n)(?:\s|\\n)*(a)(?:\s|\\n)*(b)(?:\s|\\n)*(c)(?:\s|\\n)*(n)
```

Tests:

```
\n        \nnabcn     \n      \n
```

https://regex101.com/r/SPH5mI/1

```
     \n        \n\n   n\n\n\n\nab       c\n\n\n\nn     \n      \n
```

https://regex101.com/r/ezUGes/1

As it creates as many groups as there are characteres in "nabcn" ([what does that word mean anyway?](http://www.webqc.org/molecular-weight-of-NaBCN.html)), to retrieve the word simply get the groups `$1$2$3$4$5`.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome work. But remember I mentioned in my question - "nabcn" can have any characters including newline. Your solution fails for ' 
     \n        \nabkcn     \n      \n    '. It's not just about 'nabcn'. After removing all white spaces and "\n" from start and end, the string can simply just have anything from numbers, symbols, words, to escape characters, simply anything.

Comment: I apologize I missed the note in your answer. I can't assume "nabcn" specifically to be a known string, It can be ANYTHING. I just want to remove spaces and "\n" string from the start and end of it.